# How to switch from one Sim card to the other on call in xamarin cross plate form

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, toggle, call

I wish to programmatically switch from one Sim card to the other in a dual SIM card device when calling.
I am currently using cross message plug-in to initiate a call in my xamarin form app

Comment: Actually, this is a system function for the two different platforms. I am not familiar with IOS, but for the android, there is no any api can be used to change the sim card. User can do this just by getting into the system settings on the device.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do it with Android cross plate form?..

Comment: Just like I mentioned before, there is no api can be used to change the sim card on android. For the system security, google doesn't allow developers to edit it by the 3 party app.